# Flask не подтягиваюися файлы

Tags: python, html, веб-программирование, файлы, flask

Запускаю проект на фласке, но не подтягиваются ни стили, ни изображения, какие бы пути не ставил.

путь к файлу:
D:\code\Engel’s shop\styles\style.css

`python`:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, send_from_directory
import os
import sqlite3
import uuid

app = Flask(__name__)

conn = sqlite3.connect('your_database.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
@app.route('/')
def index():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('your_database.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM products')
    products = cursor.fetchall()

    conn.close()

    return render_template('index.html', products=products)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`html`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style.css">
```

Вот такие ошибки пишутся в логах, просто не видит файлы:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2024 21:59:24]
"GET /styles/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404
- 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2024 21:59:24] 
"GET /img/logo.JPG HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2024 21:59:24]
 "GET /img/tg-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2024 21:59:24]
 "GET /img/1694176632.avif HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2024 21:59:24] "GET /styles/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2024 21:59:24] "GET /img/logo.JPG HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2024 21:59:24] "GET /img/tg-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2024 21:59:24] "GET /img/1694176632.avif HTTP/1.1" 404 -
вот такие ошибки, просто не видид файлы

Answer (score 1):

Flask ищет стили вроде как по этому пути обязательно **/static/** а далее хоть сколько вложенных папок *'/static/styles/style.css'*

**html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='/static/styles/style.css' />
```

Comment: static и main.py должны находится на одном уровне